# error package linux-extra-4.8.0.58-generic

Tags: package-management

hello please i need little help i am new in ubuntu

```
E: The package linux-image-extra-4.8.0-58-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it
```

i try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and take this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2) xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
aris@aris-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
aris@aris-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
aris@aris-Lenovo-G50-70:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f
```

thanks

aris

Comment: Please use the terminal and run `sudo apt install -f` then try the updates again

Comment: Did it resolve it...?

Comment: yes all perfect